# Angular ngModel inside ngForm with number array

Tags: angular, ngmodel

I'm stuck on an issue since a while now and I can't figure out why this is happening.

I have a `values: number[] = [10,10]` variable in my component.  When I'm modifying the first input, on the keyDown, it moves my cursor to the next input sometimes, or it loose the focus.

Here is an example Plunker : https://embed.plnkr.co/N4PO5CNvn0WJChgNIo59/

edit : the cursor move to the next input when the two values are the same. Example : 10, 10. If I will type any number, the focus will be transmitted to the next input. btw I'm using Chrome latest version

Comment: similar issue here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/eB19TlFHFVE

Comment: That's an AngularJS issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this issue, and luckily for you I remember how to resolve it !

To resolve that, you need to define a custom trackBy function.

Add this in your *ngFor :

```
*ngFor="let val of values; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn"
```

In your component TS :

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index; // or item.id
}
```

Just tested it on plunkr, works like a charm !

Comment: Thanks a lot, I love you ! It's perfect :) Can you explain what this his happening, or did you remember where did you found your solution ?

Comment: It's a lot easier when you know the origin of the issue :D [Here are both answers to your questions](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10423)

Answer (score -1):

Use following code.

```
    import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
    values: number[] = [10, 10];
    label: string;

    public updateValue(event, index) {
        this.values[index] = +event.target.value;
        console.log(this.values);
    }
}



<div class="field">
    <span *ngFor="let val of values; let i = index">
      <input type="number" [attr.name]="'test' + i" [value]="val" (change)="updateValue($event, i)" >,
    </span>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is not working, change Output is returning the number value and not a Event with a target field. You're adding the value to the values array, and that's not what I wanted to do either, this is not the feature I wanted